# Place bootstrap menu in styled div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

I have a div with css style and bootstrap menu. I want to know how can I merge that menu in the same div with css and get something like:

ABOUT US - HISTORY  QUALITY

I want to add text "ABOUT US" then use `nav` to concat menu with first text. How can I achieve that? Regards

There is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/68064/) of current menu and styled div

Html:

```
<div class="titulo" width:="100px" height:="30px" style="text-align:left;">ABOUT US</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav .font_black">
        <li>
          <a class="font_black" href="#office">HISTORY
                                            <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity"></span>
                                        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="font_black" href="#group">QUALITY
                                            <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity"></span>
                                        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="font_black" href="#global">GLOBAL PRESENCE
                                            <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity"></span>
                                        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="font_black" href="#clients">CLIENTS AND AWARDS
                                            <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity"></span>
                                        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="font_black" href="#sustent">SUSTENTABILITY
                                            <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity"></span>
                                        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="font_black" href="#legal">LEGAL
                                            <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity"></span>
                                        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.titulo {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #0039a6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Consider using the Navbar Brand and style it accordingly rather than a separate styled div
2. The BS navbar, per BS3 docs, cannot know how big your menu items are and so will wrap as needed

> #### Overflowing content
>
> Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row. To resolve this, you can:
>
> - Reduce the amount or width of navbar items.
> - Hide certain navbar items at certain screen sizes using responsive utility classes.
> - Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the @grid-float-breakpoint variable or add your own media query.

---

## Code Snippet:  Switch to Full Screen to view

```css
.navbar-brand {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white !important;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">About Us</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quality</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Global Presence</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sustentability</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```